# Examples of finite group representations on polynomials

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, finite-groups, representation-theory

Studying the representations of Lie groups on polynomials has been very valuable to me. For example, the natural action of $SO(3)$ on real homogeneous polynomials of 3 variables, or the action of $SU(2)$ on complex homogeneous polynomials of 2 variables.

I would like to have a repertoire of polynomial representations of finite groups. Are there any well known examples? I'm especially interested in polynomials of 1 variable, where the Lie group representations are not very interesting.